# What could cause a TensorFlow.js model to produce output in an unreadable format?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

My tf.sequential() model is created and the training process works (i.e. I can see the loss decreasing and accuracy improving in the visualization tab).

However, when I try to run individual test cases by providing an input and asking the model to predict the output using model.predict(input), the output I receive is in a format from which I cannot obtain a value.

```
t {isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(2), dtype: "float32", size: 1, strides: Array(1), …}
```

Here is what is inside the object if it is opened up:

```
dataId: {}
dtype: "float32"
id: 20129
isDisposed: (...)
isDisposedInternal: false
rank: (...)
rankType: "2"
shape: (2) [1, 1]
size: 1
strides: [1]
__proto__: Object
```

What could be causing this issue? Is there a way to extract a predicted value from this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is tensor. The data of the tensor is stored inside the backend (for example on the graphics card of the computer). To download and look at the actual data, you need to run the `tensor.array` (or `tensor.data`) function.

**Code Sample**

```js
const ar1 = await tensor.array(); // returns the data as array
const ar2 = tensor.arraySync(); // same, but blocks the runtime during execution

// Alternative, just the data (just as a single array):
const data1 = await tensor.data();
const data2 = tensor.dataSync();
```

It is recommended to use the asynchronous function as they do not block the execution, but be aware that you have to run them in an `async function` like this:

```js
(async () => {
  const ar = await tensor.array();
})();
```